# $(document).on 'ready page:load' - not working in ie10 correctly

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, pageload, turbolinks

i am developing in rails. for jquery i use coffeescript. turbolinks are active.

i have an issue and it gets me on my nerves.

when i want to start my function (here called scripts) i use the following code:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', =>
    scripts()
```

my script (div slider) is running when page is loaded, without any problems in all browsers.

anyway, when i click on another page and then get back to the start, the javascript is not loading. this issue is actually only in ie10.

i tried the following already:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:change', =>
    scripts()
```

.. but then the div slider gets out of control. it jumps nonrational. ;-)

what can i do? any ideas?

thank you!

st

Comment: Do not bind to 'ready' that way. http://api.jquery.com/ready

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
$(document).on 'ready, page:change', =>
    scripts()
```

add a comma between ready and page:change, to separate both parameters.