# javascript not executed unless reloading page using turbolinks and rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, jquery-tokeninput

I followed the [railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised?view=comments) , but I found I can not load the "saved tokens".

I think the problem is that when click 'edit' link (created by scaffold),

it didn't trigger the preload function, how do you fix the problems in Rails 4

[image]
View page

```
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :content
    = f.text_field :user_tokens, data: {load: @article.users}
```

My coffeescript

```
$(document).ready -> 
  $('#article_user_tokens').tokenInput '/users.json',
    theme: 'facebook',
    prePopulate: $('#article_user_tokens').data('load')
```

Require the css and js file

```
 *= require token-input-facebook
 //= require jquery.tokeninput
```

I fix the bug by this solution, use the `ready page:load`

But I can not understand, why it works

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $('#article_user_tokens').tokenInput '/users.json',
    theme: 'facebook',
    prePopulate: $('#article_user_tokens').data('load')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Answer (score 1):

When Turbolinks is enabled, Rails uses Ajax to load only the elements of a page that have changed, rather than loading an entire new page.  For this reason, there is often no page load from the standpoint of jQuery `$(document).ready`.  See [here](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html) for a great post on using .js in Rails 4.

`$(document).on 'ready, page:change'` is frequently used as the substitute for `$(document).ready` on pages which are not fully reloading because of Turbolinks in Rails 4.  I think if you switch to that your problem should go away.

Your syntax may be a little off as well with `$(document).on "ready page:load"`.  There have been [other reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789461/document-on-ready-pageload-not-working-in-ie10-correctly) of problems when you are missing a comma between `ready` and `page`.